# Воспроизведение анимации при каждой прокрутке страницы.(wow.js + fullpage.js)

Tags: javascript, fullpage, wow.js

Как сделать воспроизведение анимации при каждом скролинге слайд.
Используется fullpage.js+animate.css+WOW.js.
Страница представляет собой слайдер из за чего позиция всегда одинаковая и вот такая конструкция не работает:

```
if($(window).scrollTop()>10){
```

Каким способ можно это сделать?

```
<div class=" section fp-section fp-table active fp-completely" id="what-we-do">
                    <div class="slide">
                        <div class="slide__background slide__background_what-we-do"></div>
                        <div class="slide__content container">
                            <div class="what-we-do">
                                <div class="what-we-do__col">
                                    <div class="what-we-do__title wow bounceInDown">Чем мы занимаемся?</div>
                                    <div class="what-we-do__description wow bounceInUp" data-wow-delay="250ms">
                                        <p class="text-semibold">Мы - небольшая Российская команда дизайнеров. </p>
                                        <p>Наша студия занимается качественным оформлением проектов любого вида с полной отдачей и <br> индивидуальным подходом.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="what-we-do__col">
                                    <div class="what-we-do__title wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="550ms">Что мы делаем?</div>
                                    <ul class="what-we-do__list wow bounceInUp" data-wow-delay="750ms">
                                        <li>Оформление любого типа;</li>
                                        <li>Создание эксклюзивного логотипа;</li>
                                        <li>Интро;</li>
                                        <li>Оутро;</li>
                                        <li>Рекламные ролики;</li>
                                        <li>Монтаж видео роликов;</li>
                                        <li>Эксклюзивные вставки (Lower Thirds);</li>
                                        <li>Веб-дизайн;</li>
                                        <li>Арты;</li>
                                        <li>Создание уникальных стикеров;</li>
                                        <li>Дикторские услуги;</li>
                                        <li>Обложки для соц сетей</li>
                                        <li>Живые обложки для соц сетей;</li>
                                        <li>Паки обучения;</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Существует специальное событие:

```
let myFullpage = new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    //события
    onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){
        console.log(origin, destination, direction);
    }
    onSlideLeave: function(section, origin, destination, direction) {
        console.log(section, origin, destination, direction);
    }
});
```

Вы можете на нем переключать классы `animate.css`. И в данном случае нет необходимости использовать `wow.js`.